# how to use DWR with lazy loading in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, dwr

What is the best way to deal with DWR 2.0 and Lazy Loading in Hibernate 3, even i am using convert type="hibernate3" instead of type="bean" with Lazy Loading of ManyToOne mapped fields in Pojo.

```
DWR service configration
-------------------------
<dwr:remote javascript="operationService">
 <dwr:convert type="hibernate3" class="com.model.Enquiry">
  or
 <dwr:convert type="bean" class="com.model.Enquiry">
</dwr:convert>

in POJO
----------
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Port.class)
@JoinColumn(name="LD_PORT")
public Port getLoadPort() {
    return loadPort;
}
```

DAO Layer

```
List<Enquiry> enqList =  
getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Enquiry.class)
                                            .list();
```

while fetching the list of Enquiry Objects it is returning null to the value of loadPort when accessing on JavaScript. Is this is the problem with session at DAO layer or something else is thhre ?

can any body let me know how or whats the best practices to deal with the DWR and Lazy Loading in Hibernate? i will be thankful for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `assumeSession` parameter to your converter:

```
<dwr:convert type="hibernate3" class="com.model.Enquiry">
    ....
    <param name="assumeSession" value="true"/>
    ....
</dwr:>
```

Depending on how you have hibernate set up you may also need this:

```
<allow> 
  .... 
  <filter class=" org.directwebremoting.hibernate.H3SessionAjaxFilter"/>
  ....
</allow>
```

Explanation [here](http://www.butterdev.com/dwr/2008/12/dwr-and-hibernate-3x/)